# San Francisco -> Fiji -> Brisbane -> Melbourne, Australian Travel Declaration

Tags: international-travel, paperwork, covid-19, australia

I'm going to travel from San Francisco to Melbourne. I have a transit in Fiji (NADI airport) for 3 hours and in Brisbane airport for 2 hours. Flights are operated by Fiji airlines (San Francisco to Fiji) and Qantas airlines (Brisbane to Melbourne).

I'm going to complete the Australia Travel Declaration (ATD) now.

2 questions:

1. I need to mention flight number and departing country in Travel declaration form. Which country should be the departing country in this case... USA or FIJI? And, what should be the arriving city... Brisbane or Melbourne?
2. Do I need to complete the Queensland travel declaration form even if I don't go out of the airport in Brisbane?

Comment: Are you an Australian Citizen, or do you have an exception to enter Australia?  (The fact you don't know the name of the state you're transiting in makes me think you're not a citizen)

Comment: @Doc, I'm not a citizen but a Australian PR currently living in the US.

Answer (score 1):

[This Australia government webpage](https://covid19.homeaffairs.gov.au/australia-travel-declaration) describes the information required to complete the ATD:

> **When filling out the ATD, you will need to:**
>
> - provide your contact details, including a contact phone number in Australia
> - make a legally binding declaration in relation to your vaccination status
> - make a declaration regarding your last 14 days travel history
> - make a declaration that you are aware of the quarantine and testing requirements that apply when coming to Australia and in the state or
>   territory you are landing, and the penalties for non-compliance.

The third bullet point will include all your Australia-bound flights. Thus, the answer to your first question is not "this flight" or "that flight," but **both** flights.

You will arrive into Australia at Brisbane (in Queensland). The flight from Brisbane to Melbourne (in Victoria) is domestic, both departure and arrival airports being in Australia. To make sure that all passengers arriving in Brisbane from an overseas airport (such as Fiji) pass through Australian Immigration and Customs upon arrival in Australia, Immigration and Customs checks will be done at Brisbane. That you will not leave the Brisbane Airport is irrelevant.

Thus, the answer to your second question is you should complete the Queensland declaration form. I am unfamiliar with the existence or content of a Victoria arrival form. It may be that one flying from Brisbane to Melbourne (as you will) is required to fill out such a form as well.

Comment: Thank you so much DavidSupportsMonica. I appreciate your answer!

Comment: one more question, since I will travel from US to FIJI and then to Australia, should I mention "Yes" to this question? "Have you travelled, or will you travel, in the 14 days prior to your flight to Australia?
Note: Giving false or misleading information is a serious offence. You may also be liable to a civil penalty for giving false or misleading information."

Comment: @nobody The answer is "Yes," as all your going-to-Australia flights will have occurred within 14 days prior to your last flight from Fiji > Brisbane. If the answer is useful, please tick the check mark next to to the left of the text to "accept" it.

Comment: Thanks, @nobody. I don't see the Accept It button anywhere on the page. I cannot even vote until I have 15 reputations. Is this related?

Comment: If you can't, you can't. But it's not an Accept button, but instead a checkmark that appears to the left of the answer, between the ▲ symbol which means "This Answer is Useful" and the ▼ symbol which means "This Answer is Not Useful."

Comment: I found below note at https://www.qld.gov.au/internationalarrivalstoqld/registration. Do I still need to complete Queensland International Arrivals Registration form? "International travellers transferring directly to a domestic flight to depart Queensland without leaving the confines of the airport are not required to complete a Queensland International Arrivals Registration."

Comment: @nobody Good research! That seems to mean you don't need to complete the Queensland form. On the other hand...how would you feel if the rule changed while you were enroute or an unknowing employee demanded the form and you didn't have it? I'm risk-averse, and I would fill out the form anyway, reasoning that 5 minutes' work would ensure against the possibility of a more difficult encounter with Australian Immigration. YMMV.

Comment: Thanks @DavisSupportsMonica. I tried to fill it out. It shows that I will have to quarantine for 14 days with any of 4 below options I choose: 
1. On a direct international flight to the Brisbane International Airport
2. On a transit flight and on arrival into Australia you did not leave the confines of the airport until boarding the domestic flight
3. At the Brisbane International airport to transfer directly to a single intrastate flight without otherwise leaving the confines of the airport
4. None of the above accurately describe how I will arrive into Queensland

Comment: I filled it out too: arriving from overseas (Fiji is overseas), not a quarantine-free flight, over 18 years old, not Australian citizen or PR, not immediate family of and traveling with Aus citizen or PR, so the form says you do have to quarantine. It's their form, I presume that's the law. What's your question?

Comment: Thanks again for your response. My confusion was, it seems like I don't have to fill out the Queensland Arrival Registration form as the link I mentioned above says "International travellers transferring directly to a domestic flight to depart Queensland without leaving the confines of the airport are not required to complete a Queensland International Arrivals Registration.". Do I fall in this category as I will fly to Melbourne from Brisbane airport without leaving the airport though I will have to go through immigration? Please refer to the second part below:

Comment: Second part: If I don't fall in this category and if I have to quarantine based on Queensland's law, I would probably not travel and change my travel plan. This is very important for me as I have only 3 days left. Could you please respond to this?

Comment: Btw.. I'm Australian PR.

Comment: What is your vaccination status?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133329/discussion-between-davidsupportsmonica-and-nobody).

Comment: Sorry, I was not available that time.